# Can rsync pick up where an interrupted cp left off?

Tags: rsync, cp

If I use `cp` to copy a very large file over the course of several hours and decide to stop the operation, can rsync be used to complete the operation at a later point without needeing to re-write data?

Answer (score 1):

YES.

From `man`

> rsync reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

Comment: Only if the file copy operation leaves the partial copy in place though.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna trust you, and cancel my 800Gb transfer

Comment: I don't think that means it doesn't rewrite the file, though... If your bottleneck is writing to the target disk (and not the network transfer), rsync might not be able to help...

Comment: What happened is I would watch the files' size but it would not grow for a long time; probably because rsync was comparing the bytes to what it did not need. For a completely unrelated reason I had to remove that file anyway but that initial behavior lends credance to the documentation. It seems that bytes won't be written twice, but that it's not necessarily an "orders of magnitude" time saver

Comment: If you additionally didn't want to recheck the already copied part of the file, I think you want `--append` (based on the man page).  I haven't used that, but I sometimes use `--partial` to allow a resume in future without re-transferring the data over the network... apparently `--append` effectively implies `--partial` (looking at the questions in the sidebar).